# Nested checkbox items in Ionic

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list of items(say footballers) with categories/teams:

```
$scope.players = [
  {"name": "Messi", "team": "FCBarcelona"},
  {"name": "Neymar", "team": "FCBarcelona"},
  {"name": "Ibrahimovic", "team": "ManchesterUnited"},
  {"name": "Schweinsteiger", "team": "ManchesterUnited"},
  {"name": "Lewandowski", "team": "BayernMunich"},
  {"name": "Suarez", "team": "FCBarcelona"},
  {"name": "Ribery", "team": "BayernMunich"},
  {"name": "Martial", "team": "ManchesterUnited"},
  {"name": "Lahm", "team": "BayernMunich"}
]
```

I want a nested checkbox list of the players categorized by their teams:

[image]

I tried:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="(team, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'"
                ng-model="data.teams[team]">
  <span>{{team}}</span>
  <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="player in value" ng-model="data.players[team][player]">
    {{player.name}}
  </ion-checkbox>
  </ion-checkbox>
</ion-list>
```

And this gives me a nested checkbox with only the `team` one being able to be checked.

A better way to organise the `ng-model` would be highly appreciated.

A great addition to it would be to select/toggle all players of a specific team by checking the team name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to correctly populate the players of a team:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'"
                ng-model="data.teams[key]">
  <span>{{key}}</span>
  <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="player in value" ng-model="data.players[key][player]">
    {{player.name}}
  </ion-checkbox>
  </ion-checkbox>
</ion-list>
```

Go through this wiki to understand better : [angular-filter#groupby](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby)

Comment: What's `{{key}}` here exactly? If it's the key in the group pairs generated by `groupBy`, I already use `(team, value)` instead of `(key, value)` and display it as `{{team}}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-filter and inject it to the module,

```
var carService = angular.module('clubApp', ['ionic','angular.filter'])
```

**DEMO**

```js
var clubApp = angular.module('clubApp', ['ionic','angular.filter'])
clubApp.controller('ctrlPlayer', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.players = [{
    "name": "Messi",
    "team": "FCBarcelona"
  }, {
    "name": "Neymar",
    "team": "FCBarcelona"
  }, {
    "name": "Ibrahimovic",
    "team": "ManchesterUnited"
  }, {
    "name": "Schweinsteiger",
    "team": "ManchesterUnited"
  }, {
    "name": "Lewandowski",
    "team": "BayernMunich"
  }, {
    "name": "Suarez",
    "team": "FCBarcelona"
  }, {
    "name": "Ribery",
    "team": "BayernMunich"
  }, {
    "name": "Martial",
    "team": "ManchesterUnited"
  }, {
    "name": "Lahm",
    "team": "BayernMunich"
  }]
 

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='clubApp'>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.min.css">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.min.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrlPlayer">
 <ion-list>
  <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
  <span>{{key}}</span>
  <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="player in value" >
    {{player.name}}
  </ion-checkbox>
  </ion-checkbox>
</ion-list>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue. On running the snippet, I still see that teams are selectable whereas players are not